# How to get color map of an image in PHP?

Tags: php, image-processing

`imagecolorat` can only return the color index for a single point,

is there a function to get all colors in an image?

Answer (score 2):

```
$im = imagecreatefromgif('php.gif');
$colorCount = imagecolorstotal($im);
$colorSet = array();
for($i=0; $i<$colorCount; ++$i) {
   $colorSet[] = imagecolorsforindex($im,$i);
}
```

Comment: Each entry in $colorSet in my code is an array like: (
   [red] => 226
   [green] => 222
   [blue] => 252
   [alpha] => 0
)

Answer (score 0):

It is not very documented, but I think you could use the ImageMagick method described here : http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-getimagehistogram.php